# Search for sub child in firebase using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This should be easy and there are a lot of similar questions but nothing works for me.

[image: Firebase Structure]

Here is my code and should print a snap shot but doesn't.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()


     let Ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Exhibitors-List/join").queryOrdered(byChild: "joinID").queryEqual(toValue:"1-22")

    ref.observe(.value, with: {
      snapshot in
      var newItems: [Exhibitors] = []

      for item in snapshot.children{
        print(snapshot.value as Any)
        let joinItem = Exhibitors(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
        newItems.append(joinItem)
      }

      self.items = newItems
      self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
  }
```

I have no problem getting a snapshot when searching one child up in idComp or boothLocation but not in joinID, so is it my code or is my Firebase structure off?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a query at a location, Firebase checks every child of that location for the property that you order on. There is no data in `Exhibitors-List/join`, so the query gives no results.

Instead what you want to do is run a query on `Exhibitors-List` and then order/filter on `join/joinID/0`:

```
 let Ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Exhibitors-List/join").queryOrdered(byChild: "joinID/0").queryEqual(toValue:"1-22")
```

This would work, but only if you have the joinId you want in index `0`.

What you're essentially trying to do is a reverse lookup here. Your current data structure is good for finding the join IDs for a given exhibitor. It is not good for finding the existing exhibitors for a join ID. To allow that efficiently, you need to create an additional data structure:

```
joinIds: {
  joinId1: {
    exhibitorId1: true,
    exhibitorId2: true
  },
  joinId2: {
    exhibitorId2: true
  }
}
```

With this additional structure you can look up the exhibitor IDs quickly from `/joinIds/1-22`.

Also see my explanation here: [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)

Comment: Hello got side tracked on other work, Excellent answers gentlemen. 
You sowed me both that my database structure was off and my search was off for a child. Using your advice I solved my problem. I will ellaborate for future viewers and yourselves as experts . First let me address Franks suggestion to create an additional data structure. I did have an existing data structure see https://manufacturing.show/delmar/FireBaseJoin.png,  however Google said "Read Only mode activated" on the Join-List structure shown above, I felt since there are over 40K joins my JSON tree was inefficient c next com

Comment: The join represents an exhibitors Categories and subcategories. So I came up with scheme that we discussed a few days ago. Now I made it work using your answers. New Structure see https://manufacturing.show/delmar/FireBaseExList.png. and new swift code that works thanks to your help
 ........
      let textj = "join/"
    let text =  textj + detailNamer!
     print ("in exsubvie detail Name \(text).")
    
  let Ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Exhibitors-List").queryOrdered(byChild:text).queryEqual(toValue:1)
    
    Ref.observe(.value, with: {
      snapshot in

Comment: detailNamer is a variable such as "1-22" that comes from a previous table view.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is asking to query the location `Exhibitors-List/join`, but that location doesn't exist in your database.  As far as I can see, there is another node `0` that sits between `Exhibitors-List` and the nearest `join` child.  You can't skip elements when querying - you need to query at a path that fully exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   let textj = "join/"
   let text =  textj + detailNamer!


   let Ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Exhibitors-   List").queryOrdered(byChild:text).queryEqual(toValue:1)

Ref.observe(.value, with: {
  snapshot in
  var newItems: [Exhibitors] = []

  for item in snapshot.children{
    print(snapshot.value as Any)
    let joinItem = Exhibitors(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
    newItems.append(joinItem)
  }

  self.items = newItems
  self.tableView.reloadData()

})
```

}